# Is the Turkish word for brother(kardeş) of Indo-Iranian origin?

Tags: borrowing, turkish, persian, indo-aryan

I looked up the word for "brother" in other Turkish languages. In Ubzek it is *aka*. And in Volga Tatar the corresponding word is *abi*. The word "kardesh" sounds suspiciously similar to the Armenian word *kardash* which means stone carver. So could this possibly be a loanword from one of the Indo-Iranian languages spoken in the region?

Comment: Turkish _kardeş_ (“sibling (brother or sister)”, there is no distinction between brother and sister in Turkish) is from Ottoman Turkish قرداش‎ (_qardaš/qardeš_, “sibling”), from Old Anatolian Turkish قردآش‎ (_qardaš_, “sibling”), equivalent to _karın_ (“womb”) +‎ _-daş_ (“fellow, sharer”). _karındaş_ with the meaning ‘pregnant’ which got a semantic shift into modern _karnaş_ and _kardeş_ meaning ‘sibling’ i.e. wombmates from _karın_ (womb, abdomen, stomach-please). Source: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kardeş

Comment: Kinship terms like mother - father - sister - brother - son - daughter are almost always native words, they are never loanwords.

Comment: @YellowSky Even close kinship terms absolutely can be loanwords. Finnish *aïti* 'mother', for instance, is a loan from Proto-Germanic.

Comment: @Cairnarvon - Good to know that, thank you. Notice, I did say “almost”.

Comment: So, parallel to Greek ἀδελφός - "one womb"

Comment: @YellowSky. Wiktionary is wrong.

Comment: What about dadash (داداش) which is the informal word for brother in Persian?

Answer (score 3):

Old Turkish (from 8th century on) has kadaş and ka kadaş in the meaning “kinsman”.
Anatolian Turkish kardeş results from a folk-etymological reinterpretation of the old word, as if from karın "womb" + daş "sharer". Clauson in his "Etymological Dictionary of pre-13th-century Turkish" argues that ka is a loan from Middle Chinese, and kadaş a derivative of the former. This may or may not be correct, but in any case the form with -r- is very late.